# How to know what version of extensions are used in joomla-web-site from user's point of view?

Tags: web-application, web, joomla

The problem is: I'm a user and I'm to find out what version of extensions(modules, plugins and components) are used on Joomla-site.

In simple cases the version is already written,like here:

```
JWallpapers - A lightweight yet powerful image gallery component with community building capabilities
 * 
 * @version 2.2.2 $Id: default.css 558 2010-12-16 12:29:41Z amazeika $
 * @package JWallpapers
 * @copyright Copyright (C) 2009 Arunas Mazeika, http://www.wextend.com. All rights reserved
 * @author Arunas Mazeika
 * @license GNU General Public License v2+ (GNU GPL v2+). See license.php
 * 
 */
#picture_container,#picture_right_content,#thumbs_right_section,#thumbs_left_section,#frontend_tagging_section,#pic_tags_section
    {
    float: left;
    border: none !important;
}

.jw_category_title {
    float: left;
    border: none !important;
}
```

But how to find out the version of extensions if there is no such a record?

I also looked [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/13761/13622) but the answerer used a php-script. Is it possible for a usual user to run such a script? 
Or there is other ways to find out a version of extensions ?

Comment: From a security perspective you typically don't want to advertise which software version you're using to random site visitors.  Developers should only provide an easy method to show  the version to site admins and other trusted users.  (Exposing version numbers to the general public can reduce finding your vulnerable site and abusing it to entering a version number in a search engine once a version is known to be vulnerable ....)